# BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8 to PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb

Tags: uwp, bitmap, pixelformat

Need some help

I have an UWP app and I use mediacapture to take capture of the webcam.
The problem is that I need to use this image with an older library that use bitmap in format Format24bppRgb.
I tried to get the pixels, but cannot find a way to remove alpha.

```
            PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
                BitmapPixelFormat., // WriteableBitmap uses BGRA format 
                BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                transform,
                ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation, // This sample ignores Exif orientation 
                ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage
            );
            sourcePixels = pixelData.DetachPixelData();
```

Comment: Hello, according to the code you provided, the decoder has ignored the Alpha value of the picture, which means that the pixel bytes you obtained no longer contain the Alpha channel, and you don’t need to remove it again. In addition, the bitmap library you use should be based on `.Net Framework`, which may not be fully compatible with UWP applications.

Comment: Look like BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore is removing just the value not the byte itself. sourcePixels will still have 4bytes per pixel and not 3bytes as old bitmap library.

Comment: Yes, because the format Rgba8 we are currently using, the generated byte array must contain the Alpha segment (I apologize for not expressing clearly). At the same time, due to the limited format in `BitmapPixelFormat`, there is currently no API for directly converting the byte data obtained through `BitmapDecoder` into the byte data required by `Format24bppRgb` in the `System.Drawing.Imaging`. In addition, `System.Drawing` is not supported in UWP applications. May not be able to convert it to the corresponding `Bitmap`.

Comment: Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to rework.
Converted SoftwareBitmap to byte array and removed alpha byte.
Then added to old C++ library to process byte array instead of bitmap.